# Reputation Data on Careers one week old

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, jobs

(*Yes this question is strictly a duplicate, but the fact that it mentions the same problem in those duplicate posts and those are tagged 'resolved', obviously indicates that i am raising a fresh instance of the same problem, or documenting a problem believed to be resolved was in fact, not, or else this just isn't a duplicate at all.*)

I am pretty sure that the reputation figure on my SO Career Profile has not changed since i created the Profile (on 3 May). At this moment, it reflects my actual SO reputation as it was on 3 May, since then my SO rep has increased by about 150, with no change in the figure shown on my SO Career Profile.

If the problem is not a cache-update issue, or something of that sort, here's the only other cause i can think of: at the moment my Profile shows: *Your profile is 143 / 210 complete*. Is this the culprit--i.e., that i have not 'completed' my Profile?

I suspect not because the two items--*employer view* and *public view*--show *published* and *searchable*, respectively. (Likewise, i hope this is not true because actually completing my Profile, 210/210, would require e.g, completing form questions like whether i'm willing to relocate, etc. which cause a job-seeking status to appear on my Profile (which is not what i want to indicate at present).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry about that doug and thanks for the report. There's no problem with the completeness of your profile or anything.  Just a simple cache update issue like you originally thought.  Your Stack Overflow and Super User reps have already been synced and the rest will update within the next hour or so.

Comment: that edit from Stackoverflow into StackOverflow didn't quite do it. ;-)

Comment: @doug:  No problem, sir.