# Why is my Stack Overflow reputation on Careers is not updated?

Tags: support, status-norepro, jobs

I have an account on Careers Stack Overflow and I see the same reputation that had when I created the account. Why doesn't my account update when my Stack Overflow reputation changes?

Comment: Probably cache problems like those [reported here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90599/reputation-data-on-careers-one-week-old). Hopefully a dev would show soon and force a cache reload.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked at your Careers profile and the SO rep is the same as listed against your SO profile.

We only update this information once a day so most likely a caching issue!